# Requisição ajax com Slim

Tags: php, ajax, slimframework

Tenho um formulário e a seguinte requisição:

```
        jQuery('#cadastro').submit(function() {
        var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cadastrar",
            data: dados,
            beforeSend(xhr) {
                modalOpen();
            },

            success: function(data) {
                modalContent(data);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
```

No meu index.php onde a aplicação é carregado eu tenho:

```
$app->post('/cadastrar', function(){      });
```

Como eu intercepto esses dados $_POST no meu método dentro da rota cadastrar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro parâmetro da função de *callback* ao cadastrar a rota, é justamente as informações da requisição.

Para capturar essas informações, basta passar uma variável para ter acesso ao [request](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#the-request-body) e depois utilizar o método `getParsedBody` ou `getParsedBodyParam`, por exemplo:

```
$app->post('/cadastrar', function($requets) {

    /**
     * Caso você esteja passando um JSON, use "json_decode" para decodificar
     * Caso você steja passando um XML, use o "SimpleXMLElement" para manipular esse dados
     * Caso você esteja passando um padrão "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     *      (é quando você utiliza $("form").serialize(), por exemplo)
     *      utilize o parse_str
     */
    var_dump($requets->getParsedBody());

    /**
     * Você também pode capturar apenas um input e caso o input não exista, retorna um valor padrão
     */
    var_dump($requets->getParsedBodyParam("nome-do-campo", "valor-padrao"));

    /**
     * O getBody() método é preferível se o tamanho da solicitação HTTP recebida for
     * desconhecido ou muito grande para a memória disponível.
     */
    var_dump($requets->getBody());

});
```